# Should I put Google location API inside a Service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I have the following Service that uses Google Location Service API to get latitude and longitude, but the onConnectionFailed() method needs the activity:

```
   @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.e("Error", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }
```

So should I put this on a Service or is there anything more adequate?

This is my complete Service:

```
package com.banshai.appetit.services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class LatitudeAndLongitude extends Service implements
        ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    //Define a request code to send to Google Play services
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private double currentLatitude;
    private double currentLongitude;



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                // The next two lines tell the new client that “this” current class will handle connection stuff
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        //fourth line adds the LocationServices API endpoint from GooglePlayServices
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds


        //Now lets connect to the API
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("Service", "onStartCommand");

        Toast.makeText(this, "OnStartServce", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Disconnect from API onPause()
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /*==================================================================
                    GOOGLE LOCATION API METHODS
     ==================================================================*/

    /**
     * If connected get lat and long
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        } else {
            //If everything went fine lets get latitude and longitude
            currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

            //Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.e("Error", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    /**
     * If locationChanges change lat and long
     * @param location
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        //Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, off the cuff, I would do at least an initial connection test from the activity before starting the service, just to handle any sort of connection issues. AFAIK, those are typically one-time things (e.g., user needs to upgrade Play Services). The service can set up the *real* connection; the activity is just setting up and tearing down a connection to prove that connecting is possible.

Comment: IT's already working in the Activity

Comment: The setup and handling of GMS is rather tedious in my opinion, so just want to let you know of this library: https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation greatly simplifying the process without any loss of control (that I know of).

Comment: A suggestion that would enable you to keep the implementation in one place (i.e Service if you need continuous location updates in background) is to broadcast any errors so that they can be picked up by an activity, allowing the display of a dialog or similar to update GMS or enable WiFi/GPS etc..